# C++ system for passing events with inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, events, inheritance

I am currently programming an event passing system for a game in C++ and I thought it would be useful if the events inherited from each other in a logical way.

This means I could for example raise an event of type `NukeExplosion`, which derives from `Explosion` (which would probably derive from an empty base class `Event`) and it would get passed to all listeners to an event of type `NukeExplosion`, as well as the more generic `Explosion`.

So far I was able to come up with two possible solutions:

- Doing a `dynamic_cast` on the event for each set of listeners to the same event type. If it succeeds, I can then pass the event to all the listeners in the set.
- Adding a piece of code to each Event type which raises the event again, but with a more generic type. The event would then be passed to listeners using the result of the `typeid` operator in conjunction with a map of listeners.

I don't really like the second option, because it's error-prone, and requires me to write almost the same code in every event class.

The problem with the first option is that it might need to do a lot of `dynamic_cast`s, and I would like to avoid that.

So, is there any other way which I haven't taken into accont, or is the first option the best I can do? Or should I completely drop the inheritance of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came here with almost exactly this question.  The problem is basically that C++ won't let a function like `handle (ExplosionEvent *e)` accept an argument `e` with static type `Event *` even when the dynamic type of `e` is `ExplosionEvent *`.  It would be a nice feature to have, but I'm not quite sure what else would have to change in the language.

The Visitor pattern is the cleanest solution I can think of.  The drawbacks are that it's verbose and that it may not be cheaper than `dynamic_cast<>`.

Main.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>

class Event;
class Handler;

#include "Event.hpp"
#include "Handler.hpp"
```

Event.hpp:

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H

class Event 
{
public:
  virtual void accept (Handler *handler) { }
};

class ExplosionEvent : public Event 
{
  void accept (Handler *handler);
};

#endif // !EVENT_H
```

Event.cpp:

```
#include "Main.hpp"

void 
ExplosionEvent::accept (Handler *handler) 
{ 
  handler->handleExplosion (this);
}
```

Handler.hpp:

```
#ifndef HANDLER_H
#define HANDLER_H

class Handler
{
public:
  void handle (Event *event) { event->accept (this); }
  virtual void handleExplosion (ExplosionEvent *explosionEvent) { }
};

class ExplosionHandler : public Handler
{
  void handleExplosion (ExplosionEvent *explosionEvent);
};

#endif // !HANDLER_H
```

Handler.cpp:

```
#include "Main.hpp"

void
ExplosionHandler::handleExplosion (ExplosionEvent *explosionEvent)
{
  std::cout << "BOOM!" << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Main.hpp"

int
main (int argc, char *args)
{
  Event *event = new ExplosionEvent;
  Handler *handler = new ExplosionHandler;
  handler->handle (event);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -o boom *.cpp
$ ./boom 
BOOM!
$
```

Comment: Even though I already used the second approach I described, I actually like this solution. The only problem I can see is that in a system with a lot of handlers the empty functions in Handler would probably get called quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a dynamic cast for every listener will get really expensive for a large number of listeners so you probably will have to implement a map of typeid to listeners anyway.

My listener would have an `HandleEvent` which would take an `Event` object. This method would cast(with a `static_cast`) the base event to the event type it is expecting(it needs to trust the event dispatcher for the event registering mechanism).

I would also implement a method in the `Event` class which would return a new base event if valid because you might not want to send a base `Event`. This could be done with a macro but I have a feeling it could also be done with a template method although I haven't been able to make it work yet. The dispatcher would then get that base event before calling the event handlers and then call the handlers for the base event.

Comment: I feel that what you are suggesting is what I described as my second option. And as I said, I don't like it because it requires adding similar code to all the event classes. On the other hand, it's a fast and quite simple solution.